# Django - heroku, crash on deploy / run

Tags: python, django, heroku

My app seems to run fine locally with "heroku local web"

When I push it to heroku, it goes but seems to crash. I thought this was an issue with the Procfile but am now unsure. I have read the heroku documents on deploying with django and followed a number of YouTube tutorials. I'm just lacking the experience to understand what the issue is here.

heroku logs:

```
2016-12-08T12:00:53.156174+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-12-08T12:00:53.156184+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-12-08T12:00:53.309072+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-08T12:00:58.260750+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn demonstration.wsgi`
2016-12-08T12:01:00.654433+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2016-12-08T12:01:00.734784+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-12-08T12:01:00.747378+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-08T12:01:17.045591+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=git-api-example.herokuapp.com request_id=5849efad-36bb-4fe3-9b08-b284d54c4dbf fwd="REDACTED" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-12-08T12:01:18.314297+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=git-api-example.herokuapp.com request_id=c76d3c5f-19f2-48ac-8266-52627cdfac55 fwd="REDACTED" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
(github-api-app) ➜  demonstration git:(master)
```

Procfile:

```
demonstration git:(master) cat Procfile 
web: gunicorn demonstration.wsgi
```

Directory structure below the Procfile:

(github-api-app) ➜  demonstration git:(master) tree demonstration

```
demonstration
├── __init__.py
├── old_settings.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   └── wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
├── settings
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── local.py
│   ├── production.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│       ├── local.cpython-35.pyc
│       └── production.cpython-35.pyc
├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py

3 directories, 14 files
(github-api-app) ➜  demonstration git:(master)
```

Production settings:

```
"""
Django settings for demonstration project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'REMOVED_SECRET_KEY'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'demonstration.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'demonstration.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```

I was curious if it was ALLOWED_HOSTS but I don't believe so. I added a specific host but then defaulted it to an empty list which I believe is a sensible default in this case?

Comment: Your logs say "gunicorn: command not found". Have you included gunicorn in your requirements.txt? Show that file.

Comment: (Although no, the whole point of ALLOWED_HOSTS is that an empty list won't work in production, but that isn't your problem here.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are correct, I hadn't activated a new virtualenv (after alot of changing) before doing pip freeze. Seemed to do the trick. Also - I update allowed hosts to avoid getting 400 - explicitly include host. thanks.,