# Python/Django crash on gunicorn on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

I've deployed my app to Heroku and am getting the following error in the logs upon loading the page:

```
2016-12-09T22:47:56.020392+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-12-09T22:47:56.020401+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-12-09T22:47:56.001478+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-09T22:48:00.770182+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn surfspots.wsgi --log-file -`
2016-12-09T22:48:03.282956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-12-09T22:48:03.180446+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2016-12-09T22:48:03.300446+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I am running Python 3.5.2:

```
$ cat runtime.txt 
python-3.5.2
```

The name of my Django project is 'surfspots':

```
$ cat Procfile 
web: gunicorn surfspots.wsgi --log-file -
```

For [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039158/django-heroku-crash-on-deploy-run?newreg=9f69c49c839841f7aec1ca566bed3b4), they received the same issue and solved it because they had not installed gunicorn.

However, I do have gunicorn installed in my requirements.txt, using "pip install gunicorn"

Here is my requirements.txt file:

```
$ cat requirements.txt
boto==2.43.0
click==6.6
click-plugins==1.0.3
cligj==0.4.0
descartes==1.0.2
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.10.4
django-bootstrap3==7.1.0
django-geojson==2.9.1
django-leaflet==0.19.0
django-storages==1.5.1
django-tables2==1.2.6
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.1
Fiona==1.7.1
GeoAlchemy2==0.4.0
gunicorn==19.6.0
jsonfield==1.0.3
munch==2.0.4
numpy==1.11.2
pandas==0.19.1
psycopg2==2.6.2
pyproj==1.9.5.1
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2016.7
requests==2.12.3
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.1.4
```

This is the directory structure for my Django project:

```
$ tree . -L 2
.
├── locations
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── data
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── runtime.txt
├── surfspots
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── venv
    ├── bin
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    └── pip-selfcheck.json
```

Any tips? Thank you!

Comment: Which python version is specified in `runtime.txt` file?

Comment: Is gunicon installed just for your user, or system wide? Return code of 127 from bash means means that it can't find a path to that executable - make sure it's in the Heroku user's PATH. (See here for context: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1763178/3276583)

Comment: Is that requirements.txt committed to git? And can you show your file structure?

Comment: thank you @EugeneLisitsky! I am running Python 3.5.2 -- added that to my original post. And yes, I did specify the Python version in my runtime.txt fie

Comment: thank you @DanielRoseman! yes, the requirements.txt file is committed to git. I added my file structure to my original post.

Comment: thank you @nikobelia! I am not sure how to check where gunicorn is installed for the system? I am running my code from Heroku. Locally, it runs fine, just not on the live Heroku server. Are you able to point me how to check this using the Heroku CLI?

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, my Heroku build could not access gunicorn. However, I just saw an answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024680/7274859) that suggested that I uninstall all requirements remotely, and reinstall them. This happened to work for me! Thank you all for your prompt replies, much appreciated.